# Getting exception Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean

Tags: spring, exception, spring-boot

I am getting the below exception.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
```

Below is the my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.0.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

ext {
   aemVersion='1.0.25'
   avroVersion = '1.8.0' 
   springWSVersion = '2.2.1.RELEASE'
   jibxMinorVersion = "5"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'abc'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
   flatDir {
               dirs "${rootDir}/lib"
            }
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
    name 'springFramework'
    url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.apache.camel:camel-spring-boot-starter:2.17.2')
    compile('org.apache.camel:camel-kafka:2.17.2')
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-avro', version: '2.17.2'
    compile "org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:$springWSVersion"
    compile ('org.jdom:jdom:2.0.2')
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.4'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-kafka', version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-core', version: '4.3.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.10', version: '0.8.0'
    compile ('org.jibx:jibx-run:1.2.5'){
        exclude group: 'bcel', module: 'bcel'
    }
    testCompile ('org.jibx:jibx-extras:1.2.5'){
        exclude group: 'bcel', module: 'bcel'
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

My application is a non-web application. I run it from command line and use following code.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication implements CommandLineRunner{    
    @Autowired
    private Executor routeExecutor;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Running Application from run method..");
        this.routeExecutor.executeRoute();
    }
}
```

I don't want tomcat. I have looked for this exception and it is a common one but I do not want to add "spring-boot-starter-web" dependency because it is a non-web application. Please help me out

Comment: Probably it's because you're using webservices. Spring-ws, camel and kafka. Probably some of them is adding a web dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot has incorrectly guessed that you're trying to build a web application based on what you've got on the classpath. You can correct it by using `SpringApplicationBuilder` and setting `web` to `false` in your `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyApplication.class).web(false).run(args);
}
```